# How to pass decoded HTML strings to JS?

Tags: php, javascript, json

hi i have created a php file for users to comment in my website  this is the line

```
 $comment  = $get_row[2];
$jsonarray = array('User' => $get_row[1],'Comments' => $comment, 'Post' => $get_row[3],'Date' => $get_row[4],'Like' => $get_row[5],'Dislike'=>$get_row[6],'islike' => $is_like,'abuse' => $get_row[7]);
```

but in comment box when i enter " " " it showing like

> `&quot;&quot;&quot`;

is there any function in php to decode this string and it show as a original user entered string like " " "

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php

```
<?
$x = '"with quotes" &quot;';

print htmlspecialchars_decode($x);
?>

> php test.php
"with quotes" "
```

Comment: i had used urlencode () but it is not decoding  the string again when i enter like  " " " in comment box it is displaying as &quot;&quot;&quot;

Comment: $comment  = html_entity_decode($get_row[2], ENT_QUOTES);
this one will also work fine

Comment: htmlspecialchars_decode($x) is not working for single quotes when u enter single quotes ' ' it will show like this #039; #039;